# UNNEST and JOIN | Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm able to unnest one table in Big Query by using the following code:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(instance, line_items) FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
  FROM `shopify.orders`
), UNNEST(line_items) as item
```

WHERE instance = 1

Additionally, I'm able to JOIN this table (unnested) with another table using the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
  FROM `shopify.orders`
  JOIN `google_analytics.GA`
  ON name = TransactionID

)

WHERE instance = 1
```

However, I'm not sure how to JOIN these two tables while still unnesting the values from my first query. Any idea of how I can join an UNNESTED table with another table?

Comment: i am not sure if it is possible to answer this question w/o having details on input and expected output :o(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `join` work?

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(instance, line_items)
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
      FROM `shopify.orders`
     ) o CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(o.line_items) as item JOIN
     `google_analytics.GA` ga
      ON name = TransactionID
```